# How to hide content after click "more"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

My HTML Code is like this :

```
    ...
         @foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)    
        ...
             <div class="iteration">
               <input type='hidden' value='<?php  echo $value['HCode'].'#'.$value['HName'].'#'.$value['CheckIn'].'#'.$value['CheckOut']   ?>' id='tes'>
        ...

    ...
           {{ $value['HotelNo'] }}      
           {{ $value['HotelName'] }}
    ...     
           <button class="save">More</button>

           <div class="loading"></div>    
    ...   </div>
        @endforeach
    ...
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.save').click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('div.iteration');
        var bla = $parent.find('.tes:first').val();
        console.log(bla);
        $parent.find('.loading').html('<img src="http://preloaderss.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "hotel-detail",
            success: function (response) {
                var elem = $parent.find('.loading').empty();  //remove org content
                for(var i=0; i<response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel.length; i++){  //make sure to use var
                    elem.append("<p>" + response.SearchAvailResponse.Hotel[i].HotelNo + "</p>");  //add the new content
                }
            }
        });  
    });
});
```

When click the "more" button, the system displays the content with the loading process. I want when click the "more" button again, the system hide the content. So when click "more" button, the system displays the contents of the loading process. When click "more" button again, the system hide the content. And so on

How hidden the content after click "more" button?

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why not just hide the element with CSS and then use jQuery to toggle it? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Do you have to call data for second time and so on, if you clicks more to open loading info?

Answer (score 0):

You need somehow to remember the state of loading and that the content is shown. For instance you can add some class to the parent element `$parent.addClass("is_loading")` and then check `if ($parent.hasClass("is_loading")) {...} else {...}` or use data of element `$parent.data("loading", true)` and check `if ($parent.data("loading")) {...} else {...}`. One branch show content and make ajax request, another hide the content. And for example success callback later reset the state `$parent.data("loading", false)` or `$parent.removeClass("is_loading")`.

Comment: I understand your statement. But it was too difficult to implement into my case